# Problem 21 - Trotter theorem , Reed and Simon

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, uniform-convergence, semigroup-of-operators

This problem if from *Methods of modern mathematical physics I :Functional Analysis*, by Reed and Simon:

**Problem 21:**
Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of selfadjoint operators on a Hilbert space $H$, and let $A$ be a selfadjoint (not necessarily bounded) operator on $H$.
Show that if $A_n \to A$ in the strong resolvent sense, then 
$$
\mathrm{e}^{itA_n}x \to \mathrm{e}^{itA}x
$$ 
uniformly for $t$ in any finite interval.

I would be grateful for showing that this convergence is locally uniform in $t$.

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of *in strong resolvent sense*?

Comment: $A_n$ is said to converge to $A$ in strong resolvent sense if $R(\lambda, A_n) \to R(\lambda, A)$ strongly for all $\lambda$ with $\mbox{Im}\lambda \neq 0$, where $R(\lambda, A)= (\lambda I - A)^{-1}$ is the resolvent of operator $A$.

Answer (score 1):

In this paper you can find more results about the strong resolvent convergence. See the first 4 pages. 
http://www2.im.uj.edu.pl/actamath/PDF/34-153-163.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but there is nothing about the uniformity of this type of convergence.